# Fatal error: Class 'CI' not found after uploading to live server

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, hmvc, codeigniter-hmvc

I have a project built in Codeigniter 3 + HMVC. And Im almost done with it.
In my local copy it is working properly. But when I moved my project on a live server I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'CI' not found in /var/www/vhosts/kuni.ph/httpdocs/teradasys/application/third_party/MX/Modules.php on line 92
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Class 'CI' not found

Filename: MX/Modules.php

Line Number: 92

Backtrace:
```

And here's the code on `line 92`

```
/* find the controller */
            list($class) = CI::$APP->router->locate(explode('/', $module));
```

I dont know what is the error all about.

I also checked the `config.php` and update the base_url. And I also updated the database config.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: maybe try `$config['log_threshold'] = 0;` in `application/config/config.php` to force index.php run

Comment: Ok thanks sir Ill try it.

Comment: It's already set to `0` still can't run.

Comment: Hmmm, check your controller files. Filename should start with a capital letter and also check the classname inside  the file and make it also capitalize. Hope it will run

Comment: Ok my module controller are all lowecase and in the classname are starting with capital.

Comment: I dont know why in my local copy is working fine. :(

Comment: yep, try to change module controller to caps same as the module class name

Comment: Yes, I experienced that too. Works fine in local machine but not in live. hehe

Comment: Ok Ill try it and I hope it works. :)

Comment: what is your class name there is little syntax change in Codeigniter 3 to write class name the name is must start with caplet latter for example if your class name is module.php it should work fine on local but not on live server on liver server you must need Module.php.